# How do i convert my custom google analytics code

Tags: google-analytics

Ok i have this additional ga code and need to convert it to the new analytics.js code (universal analytics)::

```
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
  _gaq.push(['_setCampSourceKey', 'utm_source']);
  _gaq.push(['_setCampMediumKey', 'utm_medium']);
  _gaq.push(['_setCampContentKey', 'utm_keyword']);
  _gaq.push(['_setCampTermKey', 'utm_keyword']);
  _gaq.push(['_setCampNameKey', 'utm_campaign']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

Comment: Is this your actual code (in which case you are renaming the campaign parameters to their default names which should not be necessary in the first place) ?

Comment: +1 to what Eike said. How about implementing universal Analytics with Google Tag Manager?